# Get the Affected Row from PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, odp.net

I am using ODP.Net and run the PL/SQL Command to merge the table in the Oracle 10G database.
My command is as follow:

```
MERGE INTO TestTable t 
USING (SELECT 2911 AS AR_ID FROM dual) s 
ON (t.AR_ID = s.AR_ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET t.AR_VIUAL_IMPAIRMENT = 1                                               
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (AR_S_REF) 
  VALUES ('abcdef'); 

SELECT sql%ROWCOUNT FROM dual;
```

The Merge command runs successfully and update/insert as I want.  The problem is I want to know how many records are updated.

When I run the above statement, "ORA-00911: invalid character error".

Please advise me how I could get the affected rows back.  Thanks million.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up a few things: a *MERGE* statement is a plain SQL command while PL/SQL code is always delimited by BEGIN/END (and optional DECLARE). Furthermore, `SQL%ROWCOUNT` is a PL/SQL variable that cannot occur outside of PL/SQL.

And I don't quite understand whether you ran the *MERGE* and the *SELECT* statement with two separate or a common ODP.NET call.

Anyway, the solution is straightfowrad with ODP.NET: Execute the *MERGE* command with `OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`. This method returns the number of affected rows.

Comment: Yeah, it returns for simple INSERT/UPDATE statements.  Not for MERGE Statement.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is put your code in a PLSQL function that returns %ROWCOUNT.

Then call this function from ODP.net setting the command type to stored procedure and using the `ExecuteLiteral` method which is going to return you the row count as an object instance you can cast as an int.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to return just the "updated" row count.

(as already mentioned the row count is the number of affected (inserted and updated) rows)

there is a good discusion on ask tom: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:122741200346595110